# Why can't the post method in my Rspec test find the create action/route for my PostsController?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Hi I have an Rspec test:

```
require "rails_helper"



describe PostsController do 


  let(:user){create(:user)}

  describe "POST #create" do 

    it "creates a Post" do 
      expect {post :create, post: attributes_for(:post)}.to change(Post, :count).by 1
    end


  end


end
```

That is throwing the following error:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"posts", :post=>{:content=>"this is post content!"}}
```

Which means it can't find the route right?

instead of passing :create as the first argument to post I have tried, passing it the route helper user_posts_path(user) <--- (this is the route for my posts create action), but I get pretty much the same error.  Here is that attempt:

```
    it "creates a Post" do 
      expect {post user_posts_path(user), post: attributes_for(:post)}.to change(Post, :count).by 1
    end
```

which throws this error:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"/users/1/posts", :controller=>"posts", :post=>{:content=>"this is post content!"}}
```

I've also attempted to pass in the id manually:

```
id: user.id
```

as the second argument to post.

Here is the post_factory.rb since I am calling attributes_for(:post):

```
FactoryGirl.define do 

  factory :post do 
    content "this is post content!"
    user
  end
end
```

My relevant rake routes:

```
user_posts GET    /users/:user_id/posts(.:format)        posts#index
                 POST   /users/:user_id/posts(.:format)        posts#create
   new_user_post GET    /users/:user_id/posts/new(.:format)    posts#new
       edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)              posts#edit
            post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                   posts#show
                 PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)                   posts#update
                 PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)                   posts#update
                 DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)                   posts#destroy
```

My PostsController create action is alive and well too.

So I know my route is there and I have tried passing the post method an explicit route instead of :create, but I still get the same error.  I believe the problem is occurring because my routes are nested, but I need them to be nested, and would like to test them in that form so I can't change the nesting.  I'm not sure what else to do, so I've come here for help.  Thanks.

Comment: The only route I see in your `rake routes` to create a  post, is the one in which you need to pass the `user_id` as well, looks like you didn't define a `create` route for your `posts` controller.

Comment: Well, your `POST   /users/:user_id/posts(.:format)` is pointing to `posts#create`, so, you're missing the `user_id` in your request.

Comment: I've tried passing this route helper users_posts_path(user) to the post method and that didn't work either.  I'll update my question to show the error message for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `posts#create` action requires an `user_id` to be passed as a part of the url.

```
expect {post :create, post: attributes_for(:post)}.to change(Post, :count).by 1
```

should be

```
expect {post :create, user_id: user.id, post: attributes_for(:post)}.to change(Post, :count).by 1
```

`user` is available from the `user` factory which is lazily created(since you used `let` and not `let!`) when you call it inside the block.